# Find location along route that is x hours away

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

Sorry, my title may not be worded the best, but below is what I'm trying to get at.

I know how to get a route between two locations and the drive time, but what if it is a really long drive?  I know that after a certain number of hours my user should stop and get a hotel.  Is there a way, with the Google Maps API, to calculate where the user will be 5 or 6 hours into the route, so I could suggest they get a hotel room in that area (in advance) so they don't have to drive late into the night not knowing where they will stop and if rooms would be available?

Comment: Not sure if there is something for Google but a simple way could be to use GraphHopper its GPX export (also available as API) which contains timestamps for every location, then you can easily see where to look for a hotel (note: I'm the author)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and see if that can do the job for me.